# Why does this React component keep re rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks

I have this Post component which mounts if the user types in the Id of an existing post in firebase:

```
<Route path='/posts/:id' component={Post} />
```

However, console logging this component sends back the log indefinitely causing my browser and actions on the page to be really slow.

Heres the content of the Post component, I think it's something to do with the way I'm setting the state in useEffect but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried React.Memo and that didn't work:

```
function Post(props: RouteComponentProps<PostParams>) {

  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({ title: '', body: '', author: '', time: 0, photoURL: '', likes: 0, dislikes: 0});
  const [existingComments, setExistingComments] = useState([])
  const [commentContent, setCommentContent] = useState('');
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  const db = fb.firestore();
  const ref = db.doc(`posts/${props.match.params.id}`)

  useEffect(():any => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    ref.get().then((doc: any) => {
      if(doc.exists && isMounted.current) {
        setPostData(doc.data().content);
        setExistingComments(doc.data().comments ? doc.data().comments : [])
      }
    });
    return ()=> isMounted.current = false;
  });

  return ( 
  //... some html that displays the information I've got from firebase
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: add `[]` before )  on `useEffect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're updating the state inside `useEffect`, this triggers a rerender because of the state change and once the component updates, `useEffect` runs again which changes the state triggering another render cycle, because of this pattern your component keeps rerendering.

You can add a dependency array to tell `useEffect` to run only when the component mounts and also when something changes, like this:

```
function Post(props: RouteComponentProps<PostParams>) {

    const [postData, setPostData] = useState({ title: '', body: '', author: '', time: 0, photoURL: '', likes: 0, dislikes: 0 });
    const [existingComments, setExistingComments] = useState([])
    const [commentContent, setCommentContent] = useState('');

    useEffect((): any => {
        const db = fb.firestore();
        const ref = db.doc(`posts/${props.match.params.id}`)
        ref.get().then((doc: any) => {
            if (doc.exists && isMounted.current) {
                setPostData(doc.data().content);
                setExistingComments(doc.data().comments ? doc.data().comments : [])
            }
        });
        return () => { };
    }, [setPostData, setExistingComments]);
    // setPostData, setExistingComments won't get a new reference for every render so they won't cause useEffect to run
    return (<></>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Just for future reference, I also had to add `props.match.params.id` to the dependency array.

Comment: Yeah, you need to add all the variables that are defined inside the component and are used in `useEffect` to avoid stale values.